# Recompile Python 3.8 with statically linked OpenSSL on Windows

Tags: python, windows, compilation, openssl

I wanted to recompile Python because this is the way I found to ensure the minimum TLS1.2 version between the peers can be maintained. So I found this resource from [AWS SDK documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/security.html#enforcing-tls-1-2), which first compiles OpenSSL and then Python but it is for Linux system.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

OPENSSL_VERSION="1.1.1d"
OPENSSL_PREFIX="/opt/openssl-with-min-tls1_2"
PYTHON_VERSION="3.8.1"
PYTHON_PREFIX="/opt/python-with-min-tls1_2"


curl -O "https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-$OPENSSL_VERSION.tar.gz"
tar -xzf "openssl-$OPENSSL_VERSION.tar.gz"
cd openssl-$OPENSSL_VERSION
./config --prefix=$OPENSSL_PREFIX no-ssl3 no-tls1 no-tls1_1 no-shared
make > /dev/null
sudo make install_sw > /dev/null


cd /tmp
curl -O "https://www.python.org/ftp/python/$PYTHON_VERSION/Python-$PYTHON_VERSION.tgz"
tar -xzf "Python-$PYTHON_VERSION.tgz"
cd Python-$PYTHON_VERSION
./configure --prefix=$PYTHON_PREFIX --with-openssl=$OPENSSL_PREFIX --disable-shared > /dev/null
make > /dev/null
sudo make install > /dev/null
```

I could achieve the OpenSSL part but not sure with Python. From the below URL, found a way to compile Python on Windows but it is not the way I wanted to link the compiled OpenSSL.

https://cpython-core-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_cpython_windows.html#build-cpython-in-the-command-line